# How do I identify these buttons using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

So these blue buttons with the crosses next to the profiles, how do I write a line of code to return a list of all of these buttons.

Something like:

```
buttons = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("something here")
```

or

```
buttons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("something here")
```

or whatelse find_elements_by_... that works

Comment: Please don't post pics of html. Use the snippet tool available via [edit]

Answer (score 1):

I see there are multiple buttons mostly with the same class, so ypu have to use

Then iterate through all of them.

Here is the xpath

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ui_button_icon']")
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

If you want to click specific button you can use either index or relative button to other element like person name.

```
# clicking on 2nd button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='ui_button_icon'])[2]").click()
```

Here is the css

```
span.ui_button_icon
```

You can apply same logic to click on nth element using `nth-of-type`.

Comment: If you feel this issue is resolved, please accept the answer so that we can reduce the number of unanswered questions :-)